# Boxplot Question .

Tags: statistics

I have a really hard time understanding box plots. I am thinking that the highest whisker is really really small that means that the 75th quartile must be of the highest range which may cause an average to be a very high value.

Comment: It means that the top 25% values are all nearly the same (they are all squashed into that tiny upper whisker).

Comment: If that high whisker is a really large number that would mean that the values may be higher right?

Answer (score 1):

A box plot essentially tells you how far spaced are different key points in a set of data. For example, if the highest whisker is very small, that means that the maximum value in the data set is relatively low as compared to the 75th percentile. If the 25th percentile is far away from the median, that means that the data between those two ranges is spread out. What a box plot can help you know is the general shape of a distribution and its spread.